# how to display posts with even/odd number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display posts with even number or odd number in a page I tried everything but still didn't work, any help is much appreciated.
I am using `devise` for User model.

posts controller

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @post = Post.new
      end
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
      end

      def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      end
      def delete
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the operation `id % 2`, which will give you the even elements. So in your model you can pass it through the where query method:

```
Post.where('id % 2')
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (ID % 2)
```

Same case for the odd elements.

Based on @mu's addition, depending on the DB you're using it could be probable that `id % 2` doesn't work, as in the case of PostgreSQL (MySQL and Sqlite works, Oracle difficult to test it), so you could use `where('id % 2 = 0')` instead.

Comment: you mean Post.where ...etc ?? as  I am trying to display posts based on id (even or odd) but here it will bring me users with odd id which is not what I am seeking ..

Comment: That's right, just replace the User model with Post.

Comment: That `where` is database dependent. Some databases (such as MySQL, SQLite, and I think Oracle) use `1` and `0` for boolean values so `id % 2` should work but other databases (such as PostgreSQL) have actual booleans so `id % 2` would give you an error. Better to be explicit: `where('id % 2 = 0')`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that @muistooshort, tested on PG and it throws a `PG::DatatypeMismatch` error, MySQL and Sqlite works. Not tested using Oracle.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com has Oracle and SQL Server as well as PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite.

Comment: won't where(id%2 = 0) cause error isn't it supposed to be id%2 = 1 ?

Comment: It depends if you want odd or even posts based on their id value @JOJO. Thanks for that resource muistooshort, I'll take a look to add the Oracle version.